# Can I have an HTML drag-and-drop input in Microsoft Edge?

Tags: html, microsoft-edge, html-input

We are adapting our product to Microsoft Edge. We have an HTML drag-and-drop feature that works correctly in IE, Chrome, etc.

Using Microsoft Edge from Win10 Insider Preview Build 10162, the drop is forbidden. We also checked http://html5demos.com/dnd-upload doesn't work neither.

Has anyone solved this problem?

Comment: As far as we can tell it's a bug in edge right now.  I might be wrong, but no one's html5 file drag/drop uploading seems to work in Edge at the moment.  Even google drive / imgur / flickr all file drop uploaders not working - but work fine in ie11.

Comment: @MikeDriver as a side question, can you get the latest Win10 Insider previews? Our's was broken after 10162

Comment: @enyce12 can you please elaborate how that answer applies to drag drop not working in Windows 10? Did you post the wrong link?

Comment: @enyce12 by the time I asked the question win10 was not RTM, so lot of people had Win10 Insider preview, which released new builds every week. I've already seen major improvements in edge with every win10 preview new build. So, it's logic to think that a new build of the insider preview, that is, the version we had installed, could solve the problem. Doubts?

Comment: There's an issue logged on MS Connect. Please vote for it:
https://connect.microsoft.com/IE/feedback/details/1544800/ms-edge-drop-files-from-explorer-to-browser-does-not-work-as-expected

Comment: It seems not working in Edge. I'm having Edge with version 44.17763.1.0. I just tried out the sample in below link.
https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-kobcul?file=index.ts

Still, Didnt Microsoft implement.??

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Microsoft implemented this feature](https://wpdev.uservoice.com/forums/257854-microsoft-edge-developer/suggestions/8964523-support-html5-drag-and-drop-of-files-from-explorer) in EdgeHTML 13, included in Windows 10 Build 10586 (November 2015).

---

Original answer:

The `DragAndDropEntries` is not supported in Microsoft Edge yet.  See [this link](http://dev.modern.ie/platform/status/draganddropdirectories/?filter=f3f0000bf&search=drag) for more detail

It says:

> Allows dragging and dropping entire folders using HTML5 Drag and Drop. Extends the DataTransferItem with a method to get a FileEntry/DirectoryEntry.
>   Roadmap Priority: Low — We are still evaluating this technology. There may be significant spec stabilization, foundational work, or additional community input required before we can begin development."

However, feel free to request for this feature at
https://wpdev.uservoice.com/forums/257854-microsoft-edge-developer

Comment: The question appears to be for files, but the answer covers folders. Unfortunately, they *also* do not support files as of 9/9/2015: https://wpdev.uservoice.com/forums/257854-microsoft-edge-developer/suggestions/8964523-support-html5-drag-and-drop-of-files-from-explorer (at least they're working on this aspect)

Answer (score 1):

I just tried it the demo on Microsoft Edge and it worked fine for me. [image]

Comment: Greate news. Microsoft updated the uservoice page 2 weeks ago claiming it was done and being deployed in November 2015. https://wpdev.uservoice.com/forums/257854-microsoft-edge-developer/suggestions/8964523-support-html5-drag-and-drop-of-files-from-explorer
I guess it's deployed now

Comment: could you share what is your Ms Edge version(settings-->about). Ours is 20.10240.16384.0 and it still doesn't work

Comment: Microsoft Edge 25.10586.0.0
Mcrosoft EdgeHTML 13.10586

Comment: do you have Insider Preview? We don't get that update just by using Windows Update

Comment: i was on insider but now on the normal update. so the version i have now is the version that all people get with the Windows Update.

Comment: It seems to work when you drag an image from a website. However it doesn't work when dragging an image from the desktop. (Using the most recent slow ring insider build).