# Cannot Drag & Drop into MS Edge with Blueimp jQuery-File-Upload

Tags: drag-and-drop, jquery-file-upload, windows-10, blueimp, microsoft-edge

I have read that there is a problem with Microsoft Edge and all Drag&Drop sites ([Microsoft Edge html5 file drag and drop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31649569/microsoft-edge-html5-file-drag-and-drop)). I've seen this on my site using Blueimp jQuery-File-Upload.

Is it correct that we have to wait for an Edge fix from MS or is there something I have to configure in a) Edge b) Win10 or c) BjQFU?

Comment: see also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31649569/microsoft-edge-html5-file-drag-and-drop

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it correct that we have to wait for an Edge fix from MS

yes

> or is there something I have to configure

no